# Netflix: Cannot see option to watch movies online

Tags: windows, netflix

My friend just sign up for Netflix premium account. He can browse through the collections but all he sees is just an option "Add to discs". I guess, Netflix gives an option to see the content online too instead of just ordering up via DVD/Blu-ray.

Why he is not able to view the content online (similar to seeing a video in YouTube)?

Answer (score 1):

It could be one of a few things:

- Your friends account could be the 'email only' setup (If that is still available, I don't recall).
- The country/area where your friend resides/trying to play might not allow streaming.
- Silverlight might not be installed (or a linux OS that does not support Netflix).

Should be one of those, otherwise have him contact Netflix support.